# How to get Elements with Annotation in another Annotation?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have two annotations:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface A {
    Parameter[] parameters() default {};
    //other methods
}


@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Parameter {
    Class<?> parameterClass();
}
```

Use like this:

```
@A(parameters = @Parameter(parameterClass = Integer.class))
public class C{}
```

I can get elements with column annotation:

```
Set<? extends Element> annotatedElements = roundEnvironment.getElementsAnnotatedWith(A.class);
Set<TypeElement> types = ElementFilter.typesIn(annotatedElements);
for (TypeElement e : types) {
    A a = e.getAnnotation(A.class);
    //do something...
    //I can get Parameters:
    Parameter[] parameters = a.parameters();
    ...
}
```

But I can't get parameterClass directly from parameters. So I need to get Element/AnnotationMirror. Can I do that? How?

Comment: Why you can't get parameterClass?

Comment: Probably because your retention policy is CLASS and not RUNTIME. As it stands the annotation will not be available at runtime.

Comment: @MichaelWiles you are right. But I need to keep  retention policy CLASS.

Comment: @DeanXu Because of MirroredTypeException.

Comment: @android_su I have answered below. And Michael is wrong, retention policy RUNTIME is nothing with compile but runtime. Annotation with CLASS retention will maintain its information in any compile period. Even SOURCE retention is available in itself compile period.

Answer (score 0):

Class Object may not compiled in current compile period, so it may throw `MirroredTypeException`. You can get `TypeMirro` from the exception.

Here is my utility method:

```
  public static <T extends Annotation> TypeMirror getAnnotationClassValue(Elements elements, T anno,
      Function<T, Class<?>> func) {
    try {
      return elements.getTypeElement(func.apply(anno).getCanonicalName()).asType();
    } catch (MirroredTypeException e) {
      return e.getTypeMirror();
    }
  }
```

You can do

```
Parameter p = parameters[0];
TypeMirror tm = getAnnotationClassValue(elements, p, Parameter::parameterClass);
```

Comment: MirroredTypeException throws when I call parameter.parameterClass(). Not in your getAnnotationClassValue method.

Comment: @android_su Do you know Java8 Lambda? The parameter `func` is your `parameter.parameterClass()`.

Comment: Michael is right. I tried RUNTIME annotation, it works.

Comment: @android_su You are in the annotation processing, `CLASS` and `RUNTIME` is same for class in current compile period. If the class value is compiled class, for example `Integer.class`(which .class file has been in rt.jar), it will work. But when the class value is current compile period file, for example `A.class`, it will fail. Because the class has not been compiled. You can only get the `TypeMirror` not the `Class` object. I have told you all about this question. If you insist, you will meet this problem again sometime.

Comment: Sorry, I forget that I was in the annotation processing... I know the trick to get TypeMirror, and I got the TypeMirror like you said. But I don't want to use this trick, any other ideas?

Comment: @android_su This is not trick. `TypeMirrorException` gives you the `TypeMirror`, it's the correct API. The class has not been compiled, how can you get the class object? Which came first, the chicken or the egg?